# build queue issues in CC.net

Tags: asp.net, cruisecontrol.net

Having a question on how the build queue is configured in CC.net.

I believe we have an issue , when trying to “force” build a scheduled project, the server tries to run several builds at the same time and fails 
Most of them except the one that started first.

We need to get to a state when regardless how many builds are scheduled or how many we “force” start in about the same time, all build requests are placed in to a build queue and 
executed one after finishing another in the order they were placed, and no extra request are generated.

Build Failed email is sent but the build was actually successful.

In short,The erroneous email is likely due to an error in the build server’s build scheduler/queue, trying to run 2 builds instead of one when asked for a “forced” build, as a result the first one is successful and the second one fails.

How to correct/resolve this issue....?

Thanks
Nilesh

Comment: Which version of CC.NET are you using?

Comment: Cruise control .net 1.5.7256.1

Comment: It's CC.NET 1.5.7256.1.. Now can you please let me know the how to correct this...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To specify your projects' queue you need to set the queue property like this :

```
  <project name="MyFirstProject" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
```

The default value is a queue per project. If you manually set the same queue (for example Q1) for all you project then, you will have a unique queue.

As for the queuePriority, the project (not yet started) in the queue are ordonned by queuePriority, low queuePriority projects start first.

It's all described in the cc net documentation which is now offline due to a problem at sourceforge.

Comment: The erroneous email is likely due to an error in the build server’s build scheduler/queue, trying to run 2 builds(build a scheduled project of same project, the server tries to run several builds of same project at the same time and fails Most of them except the one that started first) as a result the first one is successful and the second one fails.... will the above statement solve this issue..?

Comment: By manually setting the same queue for every project in your build server, you will forbid simultaneous builds. I think it will solve your problem.